# How to put variable outside angular directive?

Tags: angularjs

Ng-table([ng-table site](http://ng-table.com/#/)) can put `$data` variable outside from their directive to 'user' domain. As long as I know, I can use and abuse this `$data` variable as I like as long as it happens inside `<table ng-table></table>` like this :

```
<table ng-table="vm.tableParams" class="table" show-filter="true">
  <tr ng-repeat="user in $data"> <---- where is this $data comes from ?

  </tr>
</table>
```

I want to do the same with my directive, so I made this:

[JS]

```
 angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Controller', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.variable = "some random variable";
  }])
  .directive('myTable', function() {
   return {
      restrict    : 'E',
      transclude  : true,
      templateUrl : 'my-table.html',
        controller: function($scope){
        $scope.foo = "hello world";
     }
  };
});
```

[HTML my-table.html]

```
<div ng-transclude></div>
```

[HTML index.html]

```
<my-table ng-model="variable">
     <div>{{ foo }}</div>  <!-- foo comes from directive, not controller -->
</my-table>
```

it works! [working sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/0ShOpcRz1aVTFEKeQe35?p=preview),
But when I add `scope` to directive :

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope:{
    ngModel : "="
  },
  templateUrl: 'my-table.html',
  controller: function($scope){
    $scope.foo = "hello world";
  }
}
```

It destroys `foo` variable so it doesn't work anymore [not working sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/UmDWM2rBnYVuMxXcEACM?p=preview).

I just want `foo` variable INSIDE the directive to be exposed OUTSIDE so I can use it in `index.html` just like `ng-table` example above. How to achive this?

Comment: Did you try `{{ variable }}` in `<div>`?

Comment: You can test it in https://plnkr.co/edit/UmDWM2rBnYVuMxXcEACM?p=preview, and yes I tried it and just as I expected, it shows nothing as `variable` is outside of directive

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your question. Does this solve your problem? https://plnkr.co/edit/RTa2dObiF1hLyIdae6Ba?p=preview

Comment: No, I just made small revision to the end of my question. I want `foo` to be exposed outside of the directive not `variable`. Look into https://plnkr.co/edit/0ShOpcRz1aVTFEKeQe35?p=preview, it shows `hello world`, it comes from inside the directive itself

Comment: @RogerNg Yes, It solves my problem, but I got another : this solution won't work for newer angular versions or maybe I'm doing it wrong. Please check here, it is a simpler version from your reference  : https://plnkr.co/edit/UmDWM2rBnYVuMxXcEACM?p=preview, notice that it works for 1.0.1 and don't for 1.3x or 1.5x ('hello' not shows up)

Comment: There was a breaking change in 1.2. The `<span>{{ isolatedAttributeFoo }}</span>` has got to be in the template. Check out this https://plnkr.co/edit/jNssHtJfxwKWu1lL0pqM?p=preview.

Answer (score 1):

if you want the `foo` to to be exposed outside so add `foo` to your scope property of directive

```
return {
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  scope:{
    ngModel : "=",
    foo : "=" //here we state that foo INSIDE will be the same as passed from higher level
  },
  templateUrl: 'my-table.html',
  controller: function($scope){

  }
}
```

and the template will look like this

```
{{bar}}
<my-table ng-model="variable" foo="bar">
     <div>{{ foo }}</div>  <!-- this is internal 'foo' now which is equal to upper 'bar' value-->
</my-table>
```

Here is the demo with your plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/VqmaxG2fIFO4k9JrQYRs?p=preview

Comment: I can't make it work for `<div>{{ foo }}</div>` below.

Comment: pls check the link - https://plnkr.co/edit/VqmaxG2fIFO4k9JrQYRs?p=preview